# Is there an equal sign with wider gap?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to make a large unary operator from an equal sign `=`, namely, `\mathlarger{\boldsymbol{=}}`, but the bars are too close together to distinguish from the general binary case. Is there some package with `=` having a wider gap that I can use?

Comment: I go with @campa 's answer because it seems most simple

Comment: I'm not sure what unary equality is supposed to denote but, if you're having trouble distinguishing your symbol for it from ordinary equality, that suggests you might want to look at a completely different symbol.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks for the suggestion, I use unary equal to refer to the set that is the isovalue contour of point p, so it can be intuitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\uneq}{}
 {
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\updraft_uneq:nn {}}
 }

\dim_new:N \l__updraft_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l__updraft_height_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \updraft_uneq:nn
 {
  \vcenter
   {
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \hbox:n
     {
      % measure the width of the equals sign in the current style
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {$#1{=}$}
      \dim_set:Nn \l__updraft_width_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
      % measure the width of 1mu in the current style
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {$#1\mkern1mu$}
      \dim_set:Nn \l__updraft_height_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
      % start drawing
      \driver_draw_begin:
      % round caps on lines
      \driver_draw_cap_round:
      % set the line width (change 1.2 to your liking)
      \driver_draw_linewidth:n { 1.2\l__updraft_height_dim }
      % 1. cm fonts use width/10  of side bearings
      % 2. the gap between lines is 5 times the line width
      % bottom line
      \driver_draw_moveto:nn
       { 0.1 \l__updraft_width_dim }
       { -2.5 \l__updraft_height_dim }
      \driver_draw_lineto:nn
       { 0.9 \l__updraft_width_dim }
       { -2.5 \l__updraft_height_dim }
      \driver_draw_stroke:
      % top line
      \driver_draw_moveto:nn
       { 0.1 \l__updraft_width_dim }
       { 2.5 \l__updraft_height_dim }
      \driver_draw_lineto:nn
       { 0.9 \l__updraft_width_dim }
       { 2.5 \l__updraft_height_dim }
      \driver_draw_stroke:
      \driver_draw_end:
      % occupy the space
      \hspace{ \l__updraft_width_dim }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mathbin{=}A$

$\uneq A$ $\scriptstyle\uneq A$ $\scriptscriptstyle\uneq A$

$A=B$

\end{document}
```

There is no “unary operator” class, one has to use `\mathbin` and TeX will act according to the context. You could also decide to simply use `\mathord`.

[image]

Comment: thank you:), your proposal is a little hard I don't quite understand, haha

Comment: @updraft I added some comments

Comment: your method is actually very thorough and illuminating I go with yours instead!

Answer (score 4):

The gap can be tweaked by changing the `4\LMpt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,bm}
\newcommand\bineq{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\vcenter{\hbox{\stackengine{%
  4\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\bm{-}}{\SavedStyle\bm{-}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}}}}
\begin{document}
${\bm{=}} A\quad\scriptstyle{\bm{=}} A\quad\scriptscriptstyle{\bm{=}} A$ bold =

$\bineq A\quad\scriptstyle\bineq A\quad\scriptscriptstyle\bineq A$ \verb|\bineq|
\end{document}
```

[image]